# Avoid CDATA tag in STYLE component

Tags: python, css, web2py, cdata, premailer

I am generating some html with `web2py gluon html` library (the application is standalone - not embedded in the web2py framework - and only using the gluon.html helpers)

I am adding some styles to it. Since I am sending the generated html via email, I am pre-processing the html with [premailer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/premailer). But premailer is not accepting `CDATA` tags:

```
cssselect.parser.SelectorSyntaxError: Expected selector, got <DELIM '<' at 0>
```

I have taken a look at the gluon code, but I do not get it:

```
class STYLE(DIV):

    tag = 'style'

    def xml(self):
        (fa, co) = self._xml()
        # no escaping of subcomponents
        co = '\n'.join([str(component) for component in
                       self.components])
        if co:
            # <style [attributes]><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/
            # style body
            # /*]]>*/--></style>
            return '<%s%s><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/\n%s\n/*]]>*/--></%s>' % (self.tag, fa, co, self.tag)
        else:
            return DIV.xml(self)
```

Currently what I am doing to build my style is:

```
STYLE('body { font: normal 16px/1.6em "Open Sans",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; } ... ')
```

Which produces:

```
<style>
<!--/*-->
<![CDATA[/*&gt;&lt;!--*/
body {
     font: normal 16px/1.6em "Open Sans",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
...
```

How can I use the `STYLE` helper to avoid having `CDATA` tags? Or do I need to do it with an `XML` helper, manually adding the `<style>` delimiter?

As a side question: why is the `CDATA` tag used at all? As far as I can see, [it is not really needed](http://www.webdevout.net/articles/escaping-style-and-script-data) for `HTML` (script and style tags are already by default `CDATA`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to put the CSS code inside `XML()`. If you don't want the CDATA tag, you're probably better off just manually writing the style tag (that's all the `STYLE` helper will do anyway).

```
XML('<style>body { font: normal 16px/1.6em "Open Sans",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; }</style>')
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up putting the style tag manually. I still wonder why is web2py using CDATA, since as stated in my question it is not really needed for html (or maybe am I wrong?)

Comment: Feel free to [post and issue](https://code.google.com/p/web2py/issues/list) about it.